# How can I auto walk in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

For my A-Frame project I want the player to move forward without depending on any controllers or keyboards. The player should always be moving forward, and should be able to decide the direction by looking around (without changing the z value). Using look-controls on the camera and movement-controls (from aframe-extras) on the rig gives this behavior, apart from the fact that it still depends on a controller. How can I implement auto walk in A-Frame?

```
<a-entity id="rig" movement-controls>
    <a-entity id="camera" position="0 1.7 0" camera look-controls>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make an endless runner of sort? What about moving the world around you? Does it have to be the camera thats moving all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the movement-control component, you can add your own "controls". As the doc say, all you have to do is to name it with a "-controls" suffix (see https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls#customizing-movement-controls ). This is the code for a simple "autowalk" custom controls component for "movement-controls":

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('autowalk-controls', {
  isVelocityActive: function () {
    return true;
  },
  getVelocityDelta: function () {              
    return new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
  }
});
```

And you can simply use it by adding it to the **controls** proprety of "movement-controls" like that:

```html
movement-controls="controls: autowalk"
```